# Shortcodes can only be used in Pages, not Posts

Tags: plugins

I've been trying to fix this for weeks now.

I want to display a certain kind of posts on all my pages at the top. The code should be located in the `header.php`. It will display sponsors, and the post will only be showing the featured image.

To do this I've tried using [Blog-in-Blog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blog-in-blog/) and [Category List Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/). Both great plug-ins to display a certain category. I've used `do_shortcode` to display the list, because originally the posts can only be displayed through `the_content();` of a page using `[blog-in-blog id=7]` or whatever.

My problem is that it will display the posts on ALL pages on my website, except for the front-page. I really can't understand this. The "Category List Posts"-plugin simply doesn't display anything, but the "Blog-in-Blog"-plugin displays an error message:

> ERROR: Blog-in-Blog shortcodes can only be used in pages, not posts.

But it's not a post. It's a page, right?

This is part of my `header.php`-file (if that could help):

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<header id="header">
<!-- Content -->
</header>

<div id="sponsors">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><span>Our Corporate/Business Sponsors</span></h1>
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[catlist content=yes title_class=header-title title_tag=h2 id=17 thumbnail=yes thumbnail_size=50,50 numberposts=20]"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll probably get help in the plugin's own [support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/blog-in-blog)

Comment: I've gone through all the support pages and googled like a madman with no results or fixes to be found.

Comment: You tried asking there? The plugin author will be the best one to answer you.

Comment: The plugin author is inactive, unfortunately.

Comment: if you look at the blog in blog code, you'll see it checks is_page(), so anything not explicitly a page will return that error (home, front page, an archive, a tag, a category, etc..). however, if you're doing this by editing a template, it somewhat defeats the purpose of using a shortcode. just skip the whole plugin thing and query for what you want directly via [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and output it yourself.

Comment: Or better yet! Post the result as an answer I'll give you best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a custom query. Try something like this (I haven't tested this code, but it should be fine): (EDIT: Changed below to "get_the_post_thumbnail", also added $post->ID)

```
<ul>
 <?php 
  $args = array(
   'cat' => '17',
   'posts_per_page'=>20
   );
  $sponsors_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $sponsors_query->have_posts() ) : $sponsors_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(50,50)) . '</li>';
  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This code displays the same one image 8 times (the amount of posts I have in category 17), and the images is from a different category. Also, it displays on ALL the pages, but not my front-page/homepage. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're passing the `size` argument as the first parameter of `get_the_post_thumbnail`, when it should be the second. Either use `the_post_thumbnail( array(50,50) );` or `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(50,50) );`

Comment: @JohannesPille fixed the thumbnail. Now correct size and corresponding image. Thanks! But it's still not displayed on the front-page.

Comment: @FrederickAndersen - are you sure the front page template calls the header file you've put this in?

Comment: Yes! It calls it. It displays everything else from it. It also displayed the error message from the `Blog-in-Blog`-plugin, so it does call it.

Comment: Whoops, forgot the post id in get_the_thumbnail. Wrote this code hastily, good catch Johannes. Code updated.

Comment: @FrederickAndersen - I'd guess there's something in your theme that indiscriminately alters queries on the front page. Check the query vars after the query via `<pre> <?php print_r($sponsors_query); ?> </pre>` to see the query sent to the database, compare them between a page that works and the front page.

Comment: Also, have you made sure there isn't some funky css going on? Have you checked the source of the page to make sure the images aren't being hidden somehow?

Comment: Would it be too much to ask, if I told you to check out the site and give me your final conclusion to the problem, because I really can't seem to find it. You need to login, because of the splash-page. https://www.daccusa.org/login - login with username: `test1` and password: `test`. You'll see if you go to any of the pages, that logos is displayed in the "Our Corporate/Business Sponsors", but when you go to the frontpage ("Home"), there's nothing there.

Comment: Well it's definitely not a css issue. Without seeing your actual theme files though, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Griffin. Milo, where did you want me to place the `<pre> <?php print_r($sponsors_query); ?> </pre>`? And just so you know, all other `do_shortcode` on the frontpage works. Thanks everybody for trying.

Comment: @FrederickAndersen after `$sponsors_query = new WP_Query( $args );`. do the shortcodes that work query the database?

Comment: I'm apparently not that intelligent, because I'm not sure where or how I can see that. Could I find it in the Google Chrome Console or could I find it by opening my WordPress database?

Comment: your home page is the 'posts page', which is not a 'page' as in 'static page' -  you will probably need to re-code your plugin(s) to get your shortcodes executed on the front page.

Comment: Do you have the slightest idea on how to do that? Or is that question rather impossible to answer?

Comment: Oh, @Milo - it does! There's a hole string of database input, where the posts should be. Would it help if you could see the Query Objects?

Comment: @Milo. I know this might be annoying, but if I write the code, that's generated by the `<pre> <?php print_r($sponsors_query); ?> </pre>`, would you then answer what's wrong so I can give you "Best Answer"?

Comment: it's a bit more complicated than just seeing that output. that was just a suggestion for you to use to begin to debug the issue, compare it with the output on a page that does work.

Comment: I'd gladly pay for your assistance, @Milo! I just need this to work asap. It's very frustrating for me.